pycharm setting to import from another directory
I am using Pycharm version 2024.2.2 and I have to update my test_api.py code to use sys.path.append  (see right pane of screenshot test api.py lines 2 and 3) to be able to import from another directory in line 4 .

I did try to set the project folder ('0_-_Learning Python') as the source folder (you can see that the top folder at the left pane int the screenshot is showing in BLUE color, signifying root folder) and it does not work.
What do I need to change in the pycharm settings so I do not need to do lines 2-3 of code and my import statement in line 4 would still work?
